# I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 7 on it. Suddenly, during Microsoft teams calls, the contacts cannot hear my voice. How can I correct?

Tags: audio, contacts, mute

I believe that I have checked sound and microphone options but I have had no success in making myself audible

Comment: As your question will limited by which versions of Teams supporting Windows 7 you need to provide information on which version of Teams your using. Screenshots showing your device settings are useful

Comment: Upgrade to a currently maintained operating system, and install Teams there, e.g., https://linuxhint.com/install-microsoft-teams-ubuntu/

Comment: Using an obsolete, unsupported OS online is an absolute no-no. Please follow the advice above.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the tree horizontal dots on MS Teams, near your account avatar, click Settings, and go to devices - there make sure the Microphone is detected correctly. There is also a "Test Call" button. If the Microphone is not detected, start a Troubleshooter to try make Windows fix the problem.
[image: MS-Teams-Settings-Audio-Devices]